# How to click “ok” in popup “Message from webpage” in selenium c#?

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I have an application in which after clicking button, a popup comes titled Message from Webpage showing the error message.I want to click Ok button on it and verify the error message.
I tried the following code

```
public void clickButtonWithOk()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(GlobalVariables.WaitTime.ToString()) * 1000);

            // Get element at runtime
            inputData = "45";
            waitForElementDisplayed();
            int runTimeObjectSize = driver.FindElements(getApplicationObject(currentObjectName, currentObjectType, currentObjectUniqueId)).Count;
            if (runTimeObjectSize == 0)
                STEPLogger.logmessage(STEPLogger.FAIL, "FAILED to click button " + currentObjectName + " Object NOT Found");
            else
            {

                IWebElement element = driver.FindElements(getApplicationObject(currentObjectName, currentObjectType, currentObjectUniqueId))[0];
                IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

                executor.ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(msg){return true;};");
                executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

                STEPLogger.logmessage(STEPLogger.PASS, "SUCCESSFULLY clicked on button " + currentObjectName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception oException)
        {
            STEPLogger.logmessage(STEPLogger.FAIL, "FAILED clickButton:" + oException.ToString());
        }
    } // End of CLICKBUTTONWithOk
```

Comment: It doesn't work *how*?

Comment: It doesn't click Ok button on popup.

Comment: Well there are a lot of unknowns here. What does `getApplicationObject` do? What does it return? What's all this javascript going on for? Is this a JavaScript alert? If so, why aren't you using inbuilt Selenium methods for it?

Comment: Actually I am using a framework in which there is a object repository excel in which we have object name,it's type(xpath/id/linktext etc) and unique id.And there is another excel which contains the keyword that is the function above(clickButtonWithOk)and many more,object name on which the function will work(feteched from object repository) and inputdata if required. So getApplicationObject will give the current objectname ,type and its unique id from object repository (for the object name specified with the keyword).

Comment: What this function does is it clicks on a button after which a popup comes.I want to click Ok on that popup.

Comment: It is windows popup.Cannot capture object of Ok button on the popup.

Comment: Here is the java solution:
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();

Comment: As it is a windows popup it is not getting handled by Selenium.Any other solution?

Comment: @Ulka - have you seen this - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744576/selenium-c-sharp-accept-confirm-box)