# How to identify that browser alert box is present on page or not by using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, browser, alerts

I am facing a issue while automating the script through selenium C#

I have a scenario in which a browser popup is displayed on the page after clicking a link.

I have to identify that on clicking the desired link whether the browser alert displayed or not.???

I need something like Is alert present ?????

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to accept the alert using try-catch: if alert accepted - step is passed, else  - failed

if you need a method try the next (checking alert present):

```
public bool isAlertPresent() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        driver.switchTo().alert(); 
        return true; 
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it click the alert? (I'm judging by your answer "try to accept the alert", coz I don't know selenium)

Comment: This method will check: is alert present or not, if alert present method returns True, if alert not present - False

Comment: Else see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744576/selenium-c-sharp-accept-confirm-box