# Selenium alert C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6xaD.png)

Hello everyone,  i'm using Chrome selenium to make a web auto.
I want to click o Add extension button
How should i to do that?
Thansk all!

Comment: This question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744576/selenium-c-sharp-accept-confirm-box

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` method.  It'd look something like:

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

Comment: i tried this. but my code throw exeption, driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); cannot catch chrome alert