# C# selenium chromedriver click on Allow store files on this device

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, google-chrome

[image]

Hi.
How can I click on 'Allow' button? I really can't find any solution in the internet. I don't want to use c++ hooks or simulate mouse clicks by coordinates. Is there any good way to allow this notification?

```
new ChromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 2);
```

doesn't help

Comment: Did you try to use [alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744576/selenium-c-sharp-accept-confirm-box) or [chrome options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515328/how-to-set-default-download-directory-in-selenium-chrome-capabilities)?

Comment: May you be more specific? Which chrome options should I use? Also it is not an alert. It is completely different thing

Comment: Maybe by launching Chrome with the `--unlimited-storage` argument?

Comment: @FlorentB. this argument just provides more than 5MB quota for storing browser files. That's it. It does not skip this 'Store files on this device' box.

Comment: You could use UI automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview. You can check before coding anything it's possible if you run the SDK's inspect.exe tool. If this tool shows the dialog box then it's actionable. Of course, this is out of selenium.

Comment: Indeed it's totally unrelated to selenium. If you provide me a link that demonstrate the behavior, I can try to publish a sample

Comment: @FlorentB. actually you answer works! I don't know why it didn't work for me in the first time, probably I was unattentive and forgot to pass options with this argument to constructor before compiling and running project. 
I decided to try it one more time after checking chromium source codes

# Prevent the infobar that shows up when requesting filesystem quota.
    '--browser_flag', '--unlimited-storage',

May you create the answer and I will give you 100 rep?

Comment: @Яктенс Тид, I'm glad it worked for you. I don't mind you writing the answer since my comment was just a guess based on the fact that the storage rely on filesystem quotas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found two solutions:

1) Thanks for @Floren 's answer: [C# selenium chromedriver click on Allow store files on this device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755558/c-sharp-selenium-chromedriver-click-on-allow-store-files-on-this-device?noredirect=1#comment96389864_54755558)

There is an argument for Chromium `--unlimited-storage`

Chromium source code reference:

```
// Overrides per-origin quota settings to unlimited storage for any
// apps/origins.  This should be used only for testing purpose.
const char kUnlimitedStorage[] = "unlimited-storage";



# Prevent the infobar that shows up when requesting filesystem quota.
    '--unlimited-storage',
```

**C# usage:**

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--unlimited-storage");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

2) @Simon Mourier's answer [C# selenium chromedriver click on Allow store files on this device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755558/c-sharp-selenium-chromedriver-click-on-allow-store-files-on-this-device?noredirect=1#comment96410631_54755558)

Click on Allow button using .NET UIAutomation

```
var andCondition = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Allow"));

AutomationElement chromeWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(_windowPointer); // IntPtr type
var buttonsFound = chromeWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants,  andCondition);
if (buttonsFound.Count > 0)
{
   var button = buttonsFound[0];
   var clickPattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
   clickPattern.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, this is an OS level dialogue, not something inside the DOM.

The way to get around it is by using desired capabilities to configure chrome to not show this dialogue.

I'm going to suggest

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", 0);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("settings.labs.advanced_filesystem", 1);
```

Other potential commands to add the options if `AddUserProfilePreference` doesn't work would be:

- `AddLocalStatePreference`
- `AddAdditionalChromeOption`
- `AddAdditionalCapability`

For more details about desired capabilities and chrome have a look at:

- [The ChromeOptions documentation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)
- [This list of command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), or the [command line switched defined directly in code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc).
- [The preferences defined directly in code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc)
- [The ChromeOptions class in the Selenium codebase](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/5bd9f79c9c236720bf08c6ed68fd9dc1a9f30fb0/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeOptions.cs)

Comment: C# selenium chromdriver does not have SetExperimentalOptions. I've already tried that.

Comment: modified it to use C# structure rather than Java one

Comment: Tried that - it does not work. No one of the options.

Comment: If none of those options work for you then you are stuck.  It's an OS level dialogue so not something that Selenium can deal with,  The only mechanism that Selenium has for dealing with things like this is DesiredCapabilities.

Answer (score 3):

```
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        var downloadDirectory = @"C:\Users\";



        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");


        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);

        IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Can you try with this one ?